# How to maintain inclusion references while loading a new form on PHP?

Tags: php, html

First of all, i want to really apologize, because my question doesnt clearly explain what i want to do. I wish my english were better.

That said, the explanation:

I have a web form called 'index.php'. On it I have included some 'reference paths' (as I call them) that are:

```
<script>jqueryUI</script>
<?php include_once('a path.php'); ?>
<link href="<'my.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

From my point of view they are all inclusions.

And i have another form, lets say 'popup.php', that should be loaded when i click a link at index.php.

What i need to do is that the new popup.php 'inherits' those inclusion paths (as i called them) automatically when it loads. In other words i dont want to include those files twice because of incompatibility issues.

How to do it?

Please be so kind to let me know if you dont understand my question, so i can think another way to explain it.

In advance, thanks.

Comment: Could you please define these incompatibility issues a little more?

Comment: I really dont know the reason. Its a plugin on Wordpress, and as far as I know there are some incopatibility issues whit jQuery. For example, when i load fancybox at the main file, everything works ok. But if I include again another jQuery based jscript it fails, and when i check at the console it says something like 'fancybox is not a function'. Also i dont want to have trouble updating relative paths on all files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of doing what you ask in PHP that I know of. However, it could be a solution to have all such inclusions in a separate file, 'include.php'. And then just include that in the beginning of each document.

Comment: Thanks, i thought about that. Problem is that, if a path changes, i have to update the relative path of each file that points to 'include.php' one by one.